# Linux device driver registering error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm having some issues with a linux device driver.

When I try to register it using

```
extern int platform_driver_probe(struct platform_driver *driver, int (*probe)(struct platform_device *));
```

it returns an error. I'm currently using Linux kernel 3.10 and I this driver was working fine in 3.2. I'm cross-compiling this kernel for an embedded system.

This might seem rather vague but I really don't have any other information that I think is useful.

Does anyone has any idea to help me debug or solve this error?

EDIT:
The error code is -19.

Comment: So you don't know what the error is?

Comment: What error?  Anything useful in dmesg?

Comment: The error code is -19, and no, unfortunately there isn't anything useful in dmesg.

Comment: error -19 is ENODEV : `#define ENODEV          19      /* No such device */`

Answer (score 1):

As 19 is `ENODEV` [error code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L22), i suppose this is where it failed in [platform_driver_probe](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/platform.c#L574)() :

```
if (code == 0 && list_empty(&drv->driver.p->klist_devices.k_list))
        retval = -ENODEV;
```

Hope this helps,